# Is it possible to do an edge swipe in iOS simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios7, uipangesturerecognizer

iOS 7 provides for a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` which detects swipes in from edges of the screen. Can this gesture be simulated using the iOS7 simulator in Xcode? Clicking and dragging outside the screen area just moves the whole simulator frame around.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't have to swipe across the edges to trigger a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, just start very close to the edge. It works if I start not more than ~15 points from the edge.

(this if for the simulator. I never tested this on a device)

---

As a side note: You have to create a gestureRecognizer for each edge. You can't OR edges together, so `UIRectEdgeAll` won't work.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/Reference/Reference.html), it gives the impression that we are able to OR the edges together.  But in practice, you are right that each edge is treated separately.

Comment: I upvoted you because of the side note. I was debugging the OR for a while until I realized that this is indeed the case. I don't know if it was implied but I did not get the sense from the documentation

Comment: Thanks @Jon! It wasn't working until I did that. Here's a sample [Xcode project and code for the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/3/21/screen-edge-swipe-gesture-on-iphone-using-the-uiscreenedgepangesturerecognizer-tutorial).

Comment: The newer answer from 2020 is a far better way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

On Simulator Version 11.4 I see the option

- `Window` -> `Show Device Bezels`

which shows a virtual device frame around the simulated phone:

[image]

This allows to start the gesture "outside" of the screen. I could successfully trigger a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` from the left.

Comment: I have been struggling with this all day long. It is working now with the default configuration of the navigation controller when dragging from the bezel.
Thank you!